# Четное или нечетное число

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду, правильно оформлен код для вычисления четного или нечетного числа. Или что можно добавить или переделать?

```
public class Chet_Nechet {
    public static void main(String args[]){
     int n = 9;
      if((n%2)==0){
            System.out.println("Число " + n + " четное ");
        }
        else{
           if((n%1)==0){
             System.out.println("Число " + n + " нечетное ");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Уже наотвечали, но `(n%1)==0` тождественно истина (любое целое делится на 1), но, поскольку этот `if` стоит в ветке `else`, то результат будет правильным.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class isEven {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 9;
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Число " + n + " четное");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Число " + n + " нечетное");
        }
    }
}
```

Названия классов надо писать на англ, транслит - плохой стиль. Также повторите приоритет операций, чтобы не писать ((n%2)==0). И еще условие ((n%1)==0) всегда дает true, значит оно лишнее. И советую не скупиться на пробелы, (n % 2 == 0) смотрится лучше, чем (n%2==0) (ИМХО)

Ну или так

```
public class isEven {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 9;
        System.out.print("Число " + n + " ");
        if( n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("четное");
        } else {
            System.out.println("нечетное");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите как можно еще проверить на четность и нечетность числа с помощью boolean?

Comment: boolen b = n % 2 == 0;
if(b) //число четно
else //нечетно

Comment: пробелы между операторами не только ваше имхо, а принятый постулат в приличном оформлении кода

Answer (score 11):

А можно "сопимайзить":) 
Следующая проверка будет работать быстрее.

Если число чётное, то его младший бит = 0.
реализация:

```
if ((n & 1) == 0) {
    System.out.println("четное");
} else {
    System.out.println("нечетное");
}
```

Comment: а ещё можно использовать тернарный оператор:
((n & 1) == 0) ? System.out.println("четное") : System.out.println("нечетное");

Comment: Возьму на заметку :)

Comment: Тогда можно ещё сократить :) `System.out.println(((n & 1) == 0) ? "четное" : "нечетное");`.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println((n & 1) == 0 ? "чётное" : "нечётное");
```

Comment: И зачем такая нечитабельная оптимизация? Вы ещё бы написали `System.out.println(((n & 1) == 0 ? "" : "не") + "четное");`

Comment: @VladD, всё замечательно читается.

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите по коду, правильно оформлен код для вычисления четного или нечетного числа. Или что можно добавить или переделать?

Неправильно. Критеческая ошибка, что для отрицательных чисел он вообще ничего не выводит.

Дальше. Зачем скобки в выражении `(n%2)==0`? И зачем второй `if`? Если остаток не 0, то число нечётное.

И ещё, если сравнивать при помощи битовой операции `n&1`, то не будет сложностей с отрицательными числами. Остаток от деления надо всегда сравнивать с нулём, а результат `&` всегда либо 0, либо 1.

Answer (score 1):

свои пять копеек:
    boolen b = (n%2 == 0);
    if(b)