# Проверить четность/нечетность числа не используя %

Tags: java

Как реализовать метод, который проверяет на четность и нечетность простое целочислеьное число?

Comment: как пример [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/27755/218319)

Comment: если "простое целочисельное число" понимать буквально, то `input == 2`

Comment: [Уже были ответы на этот вопрос:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/27592/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Answer (score 4):

Похоже, что вопрос на понимание двоичного представления целого числа.

Например для представления типа byte используется 8 бит (8 числел в двоичной системе исчисления, которые могут принимать значение 0 или 1), соответственно :

```
000 = 0000 0000  
001 = 0000 0001  
002 = 0000 0010  
003 = 0000 0011  
.....  
126 = 0111 1110  
127 = 0111 1111
```

Первый бит(здесь и далее буду считать слева) используется для хранения знака числа и будет использован для представления отрицательных чисел:

```
-001 = 1111 1111  
-002 = 1111 1110  
....  
-127 = 1000 0001  
-128 = 1000 0000
```

Таким образом, для проверки четности числа можно проверить последний бит, если он равен 0, то число четное, иначе нечетное.

Как конкретно реализовать проверку - зависит от вашей фантазии:

```
// к типу long может быть неявно преобразован
// любой целочисленный тип - преобразование безопасно
public static boolean isOdd1(long input) {
    // для проверки нам нужен только один бит, все остальные
    // нужно приравнять к 0, для этого применим побитовое умножение
    // если число умножить на 0, получим 0 
    // если число умножить на 1, получим исходное число (0 или 1)
    // пример преобразования для byte (8 бит) 
    // (XXXX XXXX) & (0000 0001) = (0000 000X) 
    // в коде используется тип long, т.е используется 64 бита
    long filterMask = 1; // маска для фильтрации - аналог (0000 0001)
    long filteredInput = filterMask & input;
    // проверка результата - сравниваем X c 1
    // где X может быть 0 или 1 соответственно
    // (0000 000X) == (0000 0001)
    boolean result = (filteredInput == 1);
    return result; 
    // или одной строкой return (input & 1) == 1;
}
```

Вот еще "плохой" пример (но работает):

```
public static boolean isOdd2(long input) {
    //получаем строку с двоичным представлением числа
    String stringRepresentation = Long.toBinaryString(input); 
    // проверяем, что последний элемент равен 1
    boolean result = stringRepresentation.endsWith("1");

    return result;
}
```

Еще несколько интересных моментов:

Побитовые операторы неявно преобразуют тип к int (или long если один из элементов long). Т.е. следующий код не скомпилируется

```
public static boolean isOdd3(byte input) {
    byte filterMask = 1;
    byte filteredInput = filterMask & input;
    boolean result = (filteredInput == 1);
    return result;
}
```

`OddTester.java:ХХ: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int
 to byte
                byte filteredInput = filterMask & input;
                                                ^
1 error`

Побитовые операторы не поддерживают ускоренное вычисление

```
public static void shortTest() {
     String s = null;
     //s.equals("") не будет выполнено, т.к первое условие дало false
     if (s == null && s.equals("")); 
     if (s == null & s.equals("")); //NPE

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно побитово сравнить с единицей, тогда данный метод вернет `true`, если число четное, иначе нечетное

```
private boolean isEven(int a) {
    return (n & 1) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если с битами не охото работать, есть такой вариант:

```
    int a = 5; //тут любое число может быть, к примеру подключить сканнер
    int b = a / 2; 
    int c = b * 2;   //если число при делении на 2 и последующим умножением на 2 не равняется изначальному числу, значит при делении отбросился остаток, а значит число нечётное
    if (c == a) {System.out.print("Это число чётное");}
    else {System.out.print("Это число нечётное");
```

Не самый лучший код, но ведь в нем главное идея