# Как работает такая проверка на четность/нечетность?

Tags: java, проверка

Встретил пример, проверка числа i на нечетность и никак не могу понять как работает данная проверка. Конкретно не понятен блок (i&1).

```
if ((i&1)!=1)
```

Comment: у нечётных чисел младший бит установлен, отсюда а проверка такая ...

Comment: @Igor ну, естественно у нечётных - опечатался

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверить четность/нечетность числа не используя %](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845042/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражение `i & 1` выполняет побитовую операцию "И" между соответствующими битами обоих чисел. Как это работает? Представте оба числа `i` и `1` в двоичной записи. Например, если число `i` равно 1234567891, то в двоичной записи из 32-х бит (размер типа `int` в Java), то есть из 4-х байт, оно будет выглядить вот так:

```
01001001 10010110 00000010 11010011
```

А число 1, в такой же записи, выглядит вот так:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

Теперь запишем оба числа в этой записи друг под другом и выполним операцию "И" между каждым битов верхнего числа со стоящим под ним битом нижнего:

```
01001001 10010110 00000010 11010011
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

Операция "И" возвращает 1 только если оба бита равны 1. В противном случае она возвращает 0. В нашем случае лишь крайнии справа биты обоих чисел равны 1 одновременно. Таким образом результат будет

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

То есть 1.

В этом и только в этом случае наше первое число является нечётным. А если бы крайний правый бит первого числа был 0, то без разницы чему равны остальные биты первого числа, результат побитового "И" со вторым числом 1 всегда будет 0.

Почему этот бит является признаком нечётности? Тут можно прочитать длинную лекцию о позиционных системах счисления, но если в кратце, то двоичная запись числа это сумма произведений цифр числа на два в степени индекса цифры начиная справа, когда первый индекс - это ноль. Например двоичное число `10111` - это справа налево: `(1 * 2^0) + (1 * 2^1) + (1 * 2^2) + (0 * 2^3) + (1 * 2^4) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 0 + 16 = 23`. Обратите внимание на то, что значение лишь крайне правой цифры может быть нечётным. Сумма любых чётных чисел всегда даёт чётное число. Сумма любого чётного числа и нечётного числа (например единицы) всегда даёт нечётное число. Именно поэтому мы проверяем лишь крайний правый бит когда хотим узнать чётное число или нет.

Этот способ работает и с отрицательными числами. Для представления отрицательных чисел в двоичной системе счисления есть несколько способов. В большинстве компьютеров, в том числе и в JVM (виртуальной Java машине), используется способ, который называется *дополнительный код*. Суть способа очень проста: берём абсолютное значение числа, заменяем все единицы на нули и все нули на единицы и затем прибавляет единицу. Результат этих манипуляций будет иметь точно такой же младший (крайний правый) бит, что и абсолютное значение числа. А отрицательное число чётно тогда и только тогда, когда чётно его абсолютное значение. Например -18 чётно, потому что чётно 18. То есть младший бит любого целого числа в Java является признаком нечётности.

Answer (score 1):

Это [побитовое умножение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%98%C2%BB_(AND)), побитово умножив число на 1 получим последний(правый) бит.