# Работа со списками в java

Tags: java, list, динамические-массивы

Вводятся три списка целых чисел строками через пробел.

Первая строка - первый список, вторая - второй, третья - третий.

Из первого списка нужно выбрать положительные элементы, из второго - четные, из третьего - кратные 7. Все выбранные элементы необходимо объединить в единый список и вывести его в порядке не убывания.

```
    Пример_1:

    Ввод:
    1 2 3 4 -2 -2 -2 -2
    2 5 4 3 9 7 8 1 7 12 16
    7 21 15 16 19 18

    Вывод:
    1 2 2 3 4 4 7 8 12 16 21

  Пример_2:

  Ввод:
  -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  7 7 7 7 7 2 1 2 1 2 1 21 21 21 21

 Вывод:
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 21 21 21 21
```

Никак не могу понять что как сделать чтобы все три условия выполнялись и заносились в отдельный единый список...

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String m = scanner.nextLine();
    String n = scanner.nextLine();
    String z = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] array = (m.replaceAll("\\D+", " ").trim()).split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(array.length);

    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(array[i]));

        if(list.get(i)>0) {
            list4.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Начал что-то писать, интуитивно и на ощущениях, но похоже не о том и не в ту степь...Подскажите, что и как лучше сделать чтоб все работало?

Comment: "интуитивно и на ощущениях" - надо писать "на знаниях"

Comment: Может и надо...но знаний настолько мало, что это похоже больше на ощущения)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо создать три списка, каждый из них отфильтровать и добавить в последний список. Затем последний список отсортировать по возрастанию. Про стримы можете почитать тут: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2203-stream-api

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().split(" "));
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().split(" "));
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().split(" "));
List<Integer> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
list1.stream()
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .filter(x -> x > 0)
        .forEach(finalList::add);
list2.stream()
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
        .forEach(finalList::add);
list3.stream()
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .filter(x -> x % 7 == 0)
        .forEach(finalList::add);
finalList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
System.out.println(finalList);
```

Если вам надо просто с пробелами:

```java
for (int i : finalList)
    System.out.println(i + " ");
```

Comment: Да, здесь все работает, но выводит в виде массива, в скобках.

Comment: Ну вот такие вещи, честно, ну изучите вы яву получше, поразбирайтесь сами. Чем больше вы не задаёте вопросов, а разбираетесь сами, тем лучше вы узнаёте яву. Ну знаете же, наверное, цикл `for`?

Comment: Да, ступил) Такую мелочь и самому было нетрудно сделать)

Answer (score 3):

```
Predicate<String> isNumber = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")
                                    .asPredicate();

List<Predicate<Integer>> predicates = List.of(i -> i > 0,
                                              i -> (i & 1) == 0,
                                              i -> i % 7 == 0);

String s = predicates.stream()
                     .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(System.console()
                                                   .readLine()
                                                   .split("\\s+"))
                                         .filter(isNumber)
                                         .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                         .filter(p))
                     .sorted()
                     .map(Object::toString)
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Два раза уже пытался отправить правку. i & 1 не работает для отрицательных чисел, а System.console().readLine() выдаёт NullPointerException.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия можете объяснить причину, по которой "`i & 1` не работает для отрицательных чисел" и в каких случаях `System.console().readLine()` может вызывать NPE?

Comment: Причина в том, что я это проверил, написав массив из чисел и проверив каждое из них на (i & 1) == i % 2 и проверив ваш код.

Comment: Если у вас NPE не выдаёт, это странно.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия [плохо проверяли](https://ideone.com/fjLjTq). Вот [хорошее объяснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/885610/204271) того, как работает проверка на чётность с помощью побитового И. Если вы сможете его понять, то для вас станет очевидно, что эта проверка не может не работать с отрицательными числами.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия `System.console()` может вернуть `null` только в том случае, если программа не подключена к консоли. Это может произойти только в трёх случаях - если это графическая программа, запущенная не из консоли, если это программа, принудительно отсоединённая от консоли родительским процессом, и если программа запущенна в IDE Eclipse. Первые два случая не соответствуют задаче из вопроса, а последний - это баг IDE.

Comment: Всё, понял, тупанул, -1 % 2 возвращает -1, а -1 & 1 возвращает 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public class Main {

    private final static BiFunction<String, Predicate<Integer>, Stream<Integer>> CREATE_STREAM
            = (s, p) -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).map(Integer::valueOf).filter(p);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String list1 = "1 2 3 4 -2 -2 -2 -2";
        String list2 = "2 5 4 3 9 7 8 1 7 12 16";
        String list3 = "7 21 15 16 19 18";

        Stream.of(CREATE_STREAM.apply(list1, i -> i > 0),
                CREATE_STREAM.apply(list2, i -> i % 2 == 0),
                CREATE_STREAM.apply(list3, i -> i % 7 == 0))
                .flatMap(s -> s)
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Конвертируйте массив в список.

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(m.split(" "));
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(n.split(" "));
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList(z.split(" "));
```

Потом, для каждого списка создайте цикл, для удобства. Нечто вроде этого.

```
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        int num = 0;
        // если строка не пуста
        if (!list1.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(list1.get(i));
        } else {
            // если внутри пустая строка, идем на следующую итерацию
            continue;
        }

        // Условие для текущего списка
        if (num > 0) {
            // Четвертый список - общий для всех чисел
            // Добавляем в него цифру, прошедшую проверку
            list4.add(num);
        }
    }
// TODO
```

А в конце, просто сортируете четвертый список и выводите.

Вот все в одном цикле, но такого лучше избегать.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String m = scanner.nextLine();
String n = scanner.nextLine();
String z = scanner.nextLine();
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(m.split(" "));
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(n.split(" "));
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList(z.split(" "));

int size = Math.max(list1.size(), Math.max(list2.size(), list3.size()));

List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int num = 0;

    if (i < list1.size()) {
        if (!list1.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(list1.get(i));

            if (num > 0) {
                list4.add(num);
            }
        }
    }

    if (i < list2.size()) {
        if (!list2.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(list2.get(i));
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                list4.add(num);
            }
        }
    }

    if (i < list3.size()) {
        if (!list3.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(list3.get(i));
            if (num % 7 == 0) {
                list4.add(num);
            }
        }
    }
}

list4.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());



// можно и так
/*
list4.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2); 
    }
});

list4.sort((a, b) -> {
    return a.compareTo(b);
});
*/

System.out.println(list4);
// можно и так
/*
for (int i = 0; i < list4.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(list4.get(i) + " ");
}

for (Integer integer : list4) {
    System.out.print(integer + " ");
}

list4.forEach((a) -> System.out.print(a + " "));
*/
```

Comment: А при помощи While (in.hasNext()) нельзя цикл в этой задаче построить?

Comment: @Сан Саныч А in это что? В любом случае, задачу можно решить любым циклом, это не принципиально. Можно даже все в одном цикле сделать,

Comment: А как в одном цикле-то её сделать можно...? Это что-то сложное совсем для моего понимания...

Comment: @Сан Саныч Это грязный код, так лучше не делать. Но если приспичило, то вычисляйте сначала длину самого длинного списка. Как пример:
    int size = Math.max(list1.size(), Math.max(list2.size(), list3.size()));
Потом заводите цикл на этот размер, а внутри делаете те же действия, что и раньше, с дополнительной проверкой. if (i < list1.size()) { // TODO }

Comment: @Сан Саныч добавил код выполнения в одном цикле.

Comment: Выглядит страшно...циклы в цикле...и в конце лямбды? Верно?

Comment: @СанСаныч, Где это цикл в цикле? Да, лямбды. На самом деле, все просто. Лямбды переделать, чтобы понятнее было? Но вообще, стоит разобраться, там все просто.

Comment: Да, можно без лямбд обоитись? Я просто до их изучения еще не добрался, поэтому не очень понимаю как они работают.

Comment: @СанСаныч добавил примеров в комментариях, можно выбирать любой, действие у всех идентично.

Comment: Благодарю! Очень помогли Ваши решения. Теперь что-то в голове стало складываться в общую картину)